# Не работает .createIndex

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Есть  коллекция, в ней надо сделать поиск. Для этого  необходимо создать индекс, который потом будет использоваться для поиска. 
Проблема в том, что через консоль я его могу создать:

```
db.films.createIndex({"title":"text", "stars":"text"})
```

А вот в express'е никак не могу.
Вот код сервера :

```js
router.post('/find', function(req, res, next) {
  Film.createIndex({
    "title": "text"
  });
  Film.find({
    $text: {
      $search: "war"
    }
  }, {
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  }, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(docs)
  })
});
```

Когда запускаю этот код, то в консоль выбрасывает ошибку **500** 
Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

С ошибкой я уже разобрался, "index не является функцией". Но теперь другая проблема, я не могу создать необходимый index через схему(модель). Пробовал так

```js
var filmSchema = new Schema( {
    title: { type: String, index: true },
    releaseYear: Number,
    format: String,
    stars : { type: String, index: true }
});
```

Но с таким образом на выходе я получаю не тот индекс, что мне нужен (т.е. такой, как я создаю вручную через командную строку)

Comment: в подавляющем большинстве случаев нет никакого смысла в создании индексов в обработчике http-запросов. индексы нужно создавать при проектировании базы данных и при, условно, поддержке. так что единственным правильным решением в это ситуации будет убрать создание индекса из роутера. а 500-тый статус ответа говорит, скорее всего, о том что такой индекс уже существует.

Comment: @norbornen Я уже нашел ошибку, при создании индекса в роутере, интерпертатор говорит, что index не является ф-цией. И яподозревал, что индексы надо задавать в самой схеме, но то что я задаю в схеме, получается не совсем так, как мне надо. Вот что я указываю в схеме title: { type: String, index: true }, но в результате я получаю не такой индекс, как хотелось бы

Comment: тебе нужно сказать `filmSchema.index({title: 1, start: 1})`, если я правильно помню

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Ovsyanka  и @norbornen за Ваши ответы. Они как раз отображают суть того, ede нужно создавать составные индексы.

В моем же случае, для поиска по двум полям, является следующий вариант, может кому то еще пригодится:

```js
var filmSchema = new Schema( {
    title: String,
    releaseYear: Number,
    format: String,
    stars: String
}); // создание конструктора
filmSchema.index({ title: "text", stars: "text" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы указываете в вашей схеме, что для двух полей нужно создать по индексу. В то время, как вам нужен один составной индекс.
В [документации](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) mongoose написано как это сделать. В вашем случае получается

```
var filmSchema = new Schema( {
    title: String,
    releaseYear: Number,
    format: String,
    stars: String
});

filmSchema.index({ title: 1, stars: 1 });
```

И хочу обратить внимание на то, что рекомендуется (там же, в документации) отключать на production системе автогенерацию индексов через установку `config.autoIndex = false`.

upd: Хотя, есть мнение, что это не так уж важно. Больше информации вот в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346910/3653002) ответе.